# Equivalent PreferredContentSize when using ChildViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

Am trying to switch over from using `UIPopoverController` to `ChildViewControllers` on iPad. We have 4 or 5 VC's that `navigate` within the parent nav subview controller, all with different sizes, each time we push or pop, the parent popover resizes based on the `PreferredContentSize` for the vc. Now have switched over to `AddChildViewController`, the parent vc keeps same size, is there an equivalent `PreferredContentSize` for `ChildViewControllers`?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Child view controllers are used by your custom container view controllers. It is the responsibility of the container view controller to specify what it wants from its children and to gather and act on that information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

Discovering there are quite a few things don't get for free with childviewcontrollers that you get with popovers, like autoresize/reposition when keyboard is shown, am doing this manually now too.

Reason needed to update, is need a full screen modal view controller over the top of the pop over view controller, so thinking was change over to child view controller and can have multiple child view controllers, where as with popover you are limited to the one on the screen, tried mixing the two but popovervc is always on top.